# Errors deploy Spring webapp to Google Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot

Firstly, I'm sorry for my bad English.
I have a Springboot webapp project, which i wanna deploy to appengine platform. The problem is when i run this project locally in appengine port 8080 using command `mvn spring-boot:run` it works perfectly. But then, when i using command `mvn appengine:deploy` the errors comes out

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
[INFO] GCLOUD: Application startup error:
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/static/ckeditor       /lang/tt.js  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/static/ckeditor/lang/pt-br.js  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/static/ckeditor/lang/no.js  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/static/ckeditor/lang/nl.js  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/static/ckeditor/lang/zh-cn.js  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/static/ckeditor/lang/en-gb.js  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/static/ckeditor/CHANGES.md  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/static/css/style.css  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/static/css/bootstrap.min.css  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/static/client_secret.json  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/articleweb/dao/NewsRepository.class  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/articleweb/service/NewsService.class  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/articleweb/controller/SampleRestController.class  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/articleweb/controller/MainController.class  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/articleweb/UploadFile.class  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/articleweb/models/News.class  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/articleweb/Application.class  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/.application.properties.swp  
[INFO] GCLOUD:   inflating: /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
.................................................................
[INFO] GCLOUD: -XX:InitialHeapSize=514850816
-XX:MaxHeapSize=514850816 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled  -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags    -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC 
[INFO] GCLOUD: openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
[INFO] GCLOUD: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-1~bpo8+1-b13)
[INFO] GCLOUD: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2017-05-30 02:17:21.237:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1794ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2017-05-30 02:17:22.251:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting umask=02
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2017-05-30 02:17:22.292:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Opened ServerConnector@29774679{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2017-05-30 02:17:22.294:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting GID=999
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2017-05-30 02:17:22.299:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting UID=999
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2017-05-30 02:17:22.309:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.3.v20170317
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2017-05-30 02:17:22.496:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor      [file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/] at interval 0
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO]   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 06:43 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-30T09:20:05+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/54M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My project's github link [here](https://github.com/NHuyHoang/ArticleWeb)
My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.hhoang.articleweb</groupId>
<artifactId>articleweb</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>articleweb Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev59-1.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.132</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>articleweb</finalName>
</build>
```

I have no ideal with this errors. Also, i'm not familiar with jetty. Hope someone help me. Thank you so much for spend time reading my post.

Comment: These are app-engine logs, can you check your application logs? Are there any timeouts observed?

Answer (score 0):

App Engine not allow Spring due to lack of some libraries.

But you can use App Engine Flexible enviroment

[Hello World Example Spring App Engine](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/helloworld-springboot)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try to deploy using a jar file.

1. Use this plugin:

   ```
     <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>repackage</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. Include any static resource if you have HTML, etc.

   ```
   <resources>
           <resource>
            <!-- Must include this for static pages -->
               <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
           </resource>
            <resource>
            <!-- Must include this for properties file -->
               <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           </resource>
   ```
3. Execute command

   mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage